# UWP create firewall rule

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10, firewall

I try to develop app for my localhost to increase my productivity and block some urls.
When I try to import **C:\Windows\System32\FirewallAPI.dll** and use its internal I get

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Creating an instance of
> the COM component with CLSID {2C5BC43E-3369-4C33-AB0C-BE9469677AF4}
> using CoCreateInstanceFromApp failed due to the following error:
> 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
> (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). Please make sure your COM object is in the
> allowed list of CoCreateInstanceFromApp.'

Do anyone know how to create firewall rule in UWP app?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netfw/nf-netfw-networkisolationenumappcontainers#requirements). It looks the **FirewallAPI.dll** does not support UWP platform. I have to say you can't use it within UWP platform. If you want to create firewall rule, the better way is use desktop-bridge to approach. And import `FirewallAPI.dll` extension part. For desktop-bridge usage, you could refer stefan's blog **UWP with Desktop Extension**.